# MinGW cmake: multiple definition of `pthread_mutex_init'

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw

Tried to build some library with Cmake on MinGW, but got this error:

```
c:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libpthread.a(libwinpthread_la-mutex.o):mutex.c:(.text+0x70): multiple definition of `pthread_mutex_lock'
lib/tokenizer/libOpenNMTTokenizer.dll.a(d000208.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libpthread.a(libwinpthread_la-mutex.o):mutex.c:(.text+0x320): multiple definition of `pthread_mutex_unlock'
lib/tokenizer/libOpenNMTTokenizer.dll.a(d000211.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libpthread.a(libwinpthread_la-mutex.o):mutex.c:(.text+0x450): multiple definition of `pthread_mutex_init'
lib/tokenizer/libOpenNMTTokenizer.dll.a(d000207.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libpthread.a(libwinpthread_la-mutex.o):mutex.c:(.text+0x490): multiple definition of `pthread_mutex_destroy'
lib/tokenizer/libOpenNMTTokenizer.dll.a(d000206.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\onmt.dir\build.make:248: libonmt.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/onmt.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:129: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please, re-add the error message into the post, and format it as a **code**, not as a *citation*. Code formatting can be performed with selecting the text and pressing `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: It's hard to figure this out without the build (compile+link) commands (especially for *libOpenNMTTokenizer.dll(.a)* and *libonmt.dll*). Most likely you're linking *libpthread* (which is static) more than once.

Comment: Did you find a good way to link 2 **dynamic** libs which are compiled with `libpthread` by mingw and causing a multiple definition of this lib then ?